# AmazonS3 client org.xml.sax.SAXParseException when trying to listObjects

Tags: java, xml, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I'm having some drama when running the listObjects(..) method of AmazonS3. I'm certain that my credentials are set up correctly as I am able to download individual files using s3Client.getObject(..). The logs read::

`com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Failed to parse XML document with handler class 
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.transform.XmlResponsesSaxParser$ListObjectsV2Handler
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.`

I understand that listObjects(..) does include in it's response some xml containing meta data. The code to reproduce the error is very simple. I can't see anything wrong here :(

ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
                  .withBucketName(ENV.getProperty("cloud.aws.s3.bucket"));

ObjectListing objectListing = 
  amazonS3Client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);

Here is the version of spring-cloud-aws-context I am using::
    `<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-aws-context</artifactId
    <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>`

Does anybody have any insight? Or know away around this issue?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution! The problem was with the permissions, apparently listObjects(..) requires it's own set of permissions. Specifically the 'ListBucket' action must be enabled.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": ["s3:ListBucket"],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::test"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject",
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:DeleteObject"
      ],
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:s3:::test/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Another issue was with how the name that I gave to my bucket. I used `mybucket/some/prefix/before/files`. I corrected this to `mybucket`. The prefix is only used with getObject(..) like this:

```
GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = new 
GetObjectRequest("mybucket/some/prefix/before/files", key);
S3Object s3Object = amazonS3Client.getObject(getObjectRequest);
```

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the exact exception ***Failed to parse XML document with handler class** * and the failure is not truly descriptive. 
But my problem was not permissions but rather trying to list the bucket subfolder directly.

I was trying to listObjects from /bucketName/subFolder/subFolder2 instead of just /bucketName and prefix.

This results in exception above (In Scala):

```
val path = "/bucketName/myFolder/subFolder"
val results = s3Client.listObjectsV2(path)
```

I needed to separate the bucket name and the prefix and then use ListObjectRequestV2

```
val path = "/bucketName/myFolder/subFolder"
val bucketName = "bucketName"
val prefix = "myFolder/subFolder"
val listObjectsRequest = new 
val ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName(bucketName).withPrefix(prefix) 
val results = s3Client.listObjectsV2(path)
```